# C troubles with infinite loop

Tags: c

I'm working on a program in C that is supposed to find instances of a word `badword` in a string `str` for a class. This is a practice exam for the exam I have tomorrow, so it's not for a grade or anything. Anyways, I think my code is getting stuck in an infinite loop but I can't figure out what's causing it. I am using printf to debug my code but it's not really helping, because I still can't isolate the problem. I think at this point I've just been looking at it for too long and I need another pair of eyes to help me out. Basically, I'm just getting it running in the loop for quite a while, and then eventually, I get a segmentation fault and the program stops. Here's my code:

```
35 int mystrlen(char * s)
36 { 
37   int i=0;
38   while(s[i] != 0)
39   { 
40     i++;
41   }
42   return i;
43 }
44 
45 char *mystrstr(char *hay, char *needle)
46 { 
47   int i=0; 
48   for(i=0; i<mystrlen(hay); i++)
49   { 
50     if(hay[i] == needle[0])
51     { 
52       int j=0;
53       int isSubString = 1;
54       for(j=0; j<mystrlen(needle); j++)
55       {
56         if(hay[i+j] != needle[j])
57         { 
58           isSubString = 0;
59         }
60       }
61 
62       if(isSubString == 1)
63       { 
64         return &hay[i];
65       }
66     }
67   }
68   return hay;
69 }
70 
71 int isSpaceChar(char input)
72 {
73   if(input == ' ' || input == '\n' || input == '\r' || input == '\t' || input == '\0')
74   {
75     return 1;
76   }
77   else
78   {
79     return 0;
80   }
81 }
82 
83 #include<stdio.h>
84
85 void censorWord(char * str, char * badword)
86 {
87   printf("Censoring Word\n");
88   char *badwordPointer = str;
89   while((badwordPointer = mystrstr(badwordPointer, badword)) != str)
90   {
91     printf("In the NULL check loop!\n");
92     printf("%d\n", *badwordPointer);
93     if(&str < &badwordPointer && isSpaceChar(badwordPointer[-1]) && isSpaceChar(badwordPointer[mystrlen(badword)]))
94     {
95       int len = mystrlen(badword);
96       int i;
97       for(i=0; i<len; i++)
98       {
99         badwordPointer[i] = 'X';
100       }
101     }
102     badwordPointer = &badwordPointer[1];
103   }
104 }
```

(Sorry about the line numbers but.. vim.. it would have taken so long to remove them)

And here's a sample output:

```
 1 censorWord Main is being run!
 2 Censoring Word
 3 In the NULL check loop!
 4 116
 5 In the NULL check loop!
 6 116
 7 In the NULL check loop!
 8 104
 9 In the NULL check loop!
10 101
11 In the NULL check loop!
12 97
13 In the NULL check loop!
14 116
15 In the NULL check loop!
16 114
17 In the NULL check loop!
18 101
19 In the NULL check loop!
20 0
21 In the NULL check loop!
22 0
23 In the NULL check loop!
24 88
25 In the NULL check loop!
26 88
27 In the NULL check loop!
28 0
29 In the NULL check loop!
30 0
....
270172 88
270173 In the NULL check loop!
270174 88
270175 In the NULL check loop!
270176 0
270177 In the NULL check loop!
270178 0
270179 In the NULL chec
Segmentation Fault.
```

Of course, the output didn't have those line numbers, because it was in terminal but I had to copy it from a txt file so that's why they're there.

If anyone can help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Use debugger to debug... Using printf is bad idea

Comment: `set nonu` will suppress those line numbers in vi.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that if your `mystrstr` function does not find `needle`, it returns it's first argument, but in `censorWord` function you compare this value with `str`, which is your initial string. So at the some point you will be infinitely comparing empty string with your initial string.
Returning `hay` from `mystrstr` in case needle is not found makes no sense to me. I suggest you to make these small changes in `mystrstr` and `censorWord`:

```
char *mystrstr(char *hay, char *needle)
{
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < mystrlen(hay); i++)
  {
    if (hay[i] == needle[0])
    {
      ....
      if (isSubString == 1)
      {
        return &hay[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return NULL; // <==
}

void censorWord(char * str, char * badword)
{
  ....
  while ((badwordPointer = mystrstr(badwordPointer, badword)) != NULL) // <==
  ....
}
```